# Dropbox Datastore API misunderstanding

Tags: c#, api, dropbox

I have just started scratching the surface about the Dropbox developer platform. I am confused about how Datastores work.

Does every user using my app have its own datastore linked to my app only? In this case, does every user have a datastore for every app? Or does every user have the entire copy of my app datastore as a whole?

Putting it differently, when I make a call to the Datastore API from my game app to store the level value, does this value go to the entire datastore in the app creator's account (where levels of all app users are stored) or does it go to the datastore specific to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Every datastore is per-user and per-app. So if you store a level value, that goes in a datastore in a single user's Dropbox, and that datastore only includes that user's data.

Comment: Thanks, but what about "Browse Datastores" option in my App Console page, whose datastores are those?

Comment: Yours. You can only view your own datastores.